# Question form my book about Zorn's lemma

Tags: elementary-set-theory, set-theory

I found that question at the end of a chapter on Zorn's lemma in my math book. There are only questions to check knowledge, but there are no answers. Could anybody tell me if I did it right? If it is correct, I don't need explanation since I understand that. However, if some of them are wrong I would like to know why exactly.

$X$ and $Y$ are arbitrary sets and $\mathcal{X}=\{⟨A,f⟩:f∈Y^A, A⊆X,f $ is injective$ \}$.
$⟨A,f⟩,⟨B,g⟩∈\mathcal{X}$, and $⟨A,f⟩≤⟨B,g⟩$, only if $A⊆B$ and $g↾A=f$. Then:

1. If $\langle A,f\rangle$ is a maximal element in $\mathcal{X}$, then $A=X$. $\implies$ correct
2. If $\langle A,f\rangle$ is a maximal element in $\mathcal{X}$, then $A=X$ or $f$ is onto $Y$. $\implies$ correct
3. If $L\subseteq \mathcal{X}$ is a string, then $\bigcup\{f:\exists A\langle A,f\rangle\in L\}$ is an injective function $\bigcup\{A:\exists f\langle A,f\rangle\in L\}\to Y$. $\implies$ I don't understand that one
4. If $\langle A,f\rangle$ is a maximal element in $\mathcal{X}$, then $f$ is onto $Y$. $\implies$ wrong
5. The existence of a maximal element in this order proves that $|X|≤|Y|$ or $|Y|≤|X|$. $\implies$ correct

I didn't split my question into $5$ independent ones since I think some of them are connected $(1, 2, 4)$.

Comment: Please check the wording: this uses $X$ for two different things.

Comment: Oh, you are right. Those are 2 different X's. I am correcting it. Thank you.

Comment: In the answer that I’m writing I’m using $\mathscr{X}$ (`\mathscr{X}`) for the partial order.

Comment: Actually, (5) is related to (2) as much as (1) is related to (4). And (3) is really just the proof that the conditions for Zorn's lemma hold for $\cal X$.

Comment: It is a good habit to try and put some concrete sets and try it out. We like to think about mathematics as different from the natural sciences, but we do well to experiment, and using concrete sets would be a good experiment here.

If you put $X=\{0,1,2\}$ and $Y=\{5,6\}$, for example, you can immediately see that (1) is false, and that (4) is false as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m going to use $\mathscr{X}$ for the partially ordered set and $X$ for the set that is a superset of the first components of the ordered pairs in $\mathscr{X}$. Thus, I interpret (1) as saying that if $\langle A,f\rangle$ is a maximal element in $\mathscr{X}$, then $A=X$. This is not necessarily true. For instance, if $X=\{0,1\}$ and $Y=\{0\}$, there is no injection from $X$ to $Y$, and the maximal elements of $\mathscr{X}$ are $\langle\{0\},\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}\rangle$ and $\langle\{1\},\{\langle 1,0\rangle\}\rangle$. You will always run into this problem when $|X|>|Y|$.

(2), on the other hand, is (as you say) true, assuming that the first $X$ is really $\mathscr{X}$: if $A\subsetneqq X$ and $f$ is not onto $Y$, then there are $x\in X\setminus A$ and $y\in Y\setminus f[A]$, and $\langle A\cup\{x\},f\cup\{\langle x,y\rangle\}\rangle$ is a member of $\mathscr{X}$ strictly larger than $\langle A,f\rangle$.

(3) is true. Let $\mathscr{L}$ be a chain in $\mathscr{X}$, let $g=\bigcup\{f:\exists A\subseteq X(\langle A,f\rangle\in\mathscr{L})\}$, and let $B=\bigcup\{A\subseteq X:\exists f\in Y^A(\langle A,f\rangle\in\mathscr{L})\}$; we want to show that $g$ is an injection from $B$ into $Y$. First we must show that $g$ is a function. Suppose that $a\in A$, $y_1,y_2\in Y$, and $\langle a,y_1\rangle,\langle a,y_2\rangle\in g$. Then there are $\langle A_1,f_1\rangle,\langle A_2,f_2\rangle\in\mathscr{L}$ such that $\langle a,y_1\rangle\in f_1$ and $\langle a,y_2\rangle\in f_2$. $\mathscr{L}$ is a chain, so without loss of generality we may assume that $A_1\subseteq A_2$, and $f_2\upharpoonright A_1=f_1$. Then $a\in A_1$, so $f_2(a)=f_1(a)$, and $g$ is therefore a function. Now suppose that $b\in B$. Then there is some $\langle A,f\rangle\in\mathscr{L}$ such that $b\in A$, so $b\in\operatorname{dom}f$, $\langle b,f(b)\rangle\in f\subseteq g$, and $b\in\operatorname{dom}g$. It’s equally easy to check that $\operatorname{dom}g\subseteq B$, so $B=\operatorname{dom}g$. The last step, which I’ll leave to you, is verifying that $g$ is injective; the argument is very much like the proof that $g$ is a function.

Yes, (4) is correct: this time the problem arises when $|X|<|Y|$. And as you say, (5) is also correct: either you get an injection from $X$ into $Y$, or you get the inverse of an injection from $Y$ into $X$.